# Are there any possibilities how to forbid clone method for all classes in java using some of jvm parameter?

Tags: java

Are there any possibilities how to forbid clone method for all classes in java using some of jvm parameter?

I don't want to explicitly override clone method in all classes.

Comment: You do not have to override that method. `Object`is not an interface that you have to implement.

Comment: If you want to forbid clone method, you need to override it. For example: @Override public final Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
  }

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option or facility.

(And for good reason.  If you could stop clone from working via a JVM switch or similar, it would most likely cause a lot of library code to break.  That may include Java SE library code.)

However, it is worth noting that by default the `clone()` method is `protected`.  Someone needs to make a conscious decision to make a class cloneable by "non-related" code.

The other approach you could take is to create a custom rule for a static source code analyser such as PMD to flag either the declaration of a `public clone` method, or calls to `clone` ... in *your* codebase.  In some respects that is better that overriding `clone()` to throw an exception.  With a static analyser, you would pick up the violation at build time rather than at runtime.